# Inequality involving norms.

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

Suppose $p,q,r \in[1, \infty)$ and ${1\over r} =  {1\over p} + {1\over q}$ .

How can I use Minkowski's Inequality for prove below?
$$||fg||_r \le ||f||_p||g||_q$$

Comment: It is called Hölder's inequality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality#Generalization_of_H.C3.B6lder.27s_inequality

Comment: [A simple proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Proof_of_H.C3.B6lder.27s_inequality).

Comment: As did showed you how to do the case $r=1$ for the general case just use the $r=1$ case on $\|f^r g^r\|_1$.